# Getting Exception when using NHibernate 2.1 Linq<T> , why?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

When using the NHibernate 2.1 with Linq assembly, we get an exception when trying to enumerate the results or invoking ToList().

we have a list of `Id` that we want to get the records of them, we used the following code

```
public List<TEntity> GetAllContainsItems<TEntity>(List<int> ids) 
    where TEntity : IEntity
{
    using (IUnitOfWork uof = _container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>())
    {
        uof.Initialize();

        IRepository<TEntity> rep 
            = _container.Resolve<IRepository<TEntity>>();

        // repository exposes the ISession.Linq<T> of nhibernate.
        var res = rep.Find().Where(y => ids.Contains(y.Id) );

        // get the exception:
        // "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

        return res.ToList();
    }
}
```

any thoughts ?

P.S.
We can't change the Dll for now .

Comment: That Select(x => x) seems redundant. Is there a specific reason for it?

Comment: Additionally, could it be that `ids` is `null`? I'd recommend you put a check for it at the top of the method and throw `ArgumentNullException` if it is.

Comment: Sorry the Select is a check by my end it should not be there. the ids is not null, when doing Find() i get all the records

Comment: Do you have a stack trace to indicate in what component the exception originates?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code to the following and see if it works:

```
if(ids==null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Why am I not surprised");
}
var res = rep.Find().Where(y => y!=null && ids.Contains(y.Id));
return res.ToList();
```

Comment: the `rep.Finq()` simply exposes the ISession.Linq<T> of Nhibernate

Comment: still returns the same exception, if i just leave it as Find i get the whole set of records. is it possible that its an Nhibernate bug ?

Comment: I dont think so. Can I see implementation of Find()?? also updating the answer again

Comment: I like your `Console.WriteLine ... ` have some faith, but the answer is have faith in me when i say that the data is not null, the following code does works due to the load of data `rep.Find().AsEnumerable().Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))`

Comment: Ah sorry, but sometimes u need to be sure :D!!  oh wait do you want to run this query on your db?? Contains cannot be translated to a db query statement and the data is retrieved into the web server.. and also Find() implementation please

Comment: `public IQueryable<T> Find(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] loadNavigationProperties)
        {
            if (loadNavigationProperties != null && loadNavigationProperties.Length > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("NhibernateRepository not supporting loadNavigationProperties");
            }
            return NhibernateUnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Linq<T>();
        }`